# Маршрутизация 2 сетевых карт на xubuntu

Tags: linux, сеть, xubuntu

Есть машина с 2 сетевыми картами на `xubuntu`:

```
enp1s0 первая
Ip : 192.168.0.253
Маска: 255.255.255.0
Шлюз: 192.168.0.1
```

```
enp2s0 вторая
Ip : 172.17.34.215
Маска: 255.255.255.0
Шлюз: 172.17.34.1
```

Одна должна смотреть в сеть интернет (enp2s0), другая в локальную сеть (enp1s0).

Так как нет возможности вносить конфигурации в машину локально (машина находится удаленно), аналогичные ответы на вопрос протестировать не могу (цена ошибки - неделя потерянного времени).

Что нужно сделать и что прописать в `etc/network/interface` для бесперебойного корректного подключения после перезагрузки к сетевому интерфейсу с выходом в интернет и постоянного просмотра локалки?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

что необходимо:

1. у компьютеров в локальной сети шлюзом по умолчанию должен быть указан настраиваемый вами шлюз
2. на шлюзе должен быть разрешён «forwarding» пакетов — передача пакетов между интерфейсами
3. на шлюзе должен быть настроен «[mascuerading](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3)» — подмена адреса отправителя у пакетов, пришедших из локальной сети и отправляющихся во внешнюю сеть: вместо адреса из локальной сети должен подставляться адрес шлюза, закреплённый за интерфейсом, подключенным к внешней сети
4. лучше заранее провести хотя бы поверхностный анализ уже существующих правил netfilter-а на предмет: не заблокируют ли какие-нибудь из них требующийся вам трафик.

к содержимому файлов `/etc/network/interfaces{,.d/*}` хоть какое-то отношение имеет разве что третий пункт: действительно, часто используется добавление/удаление правил netfiter-а в соответствующих директивах up/down в описании интерфейса в этих файлах.

Comment: Локальная сеть представляет из себя лишь свитч с камерами.(единственное что мне нужно это одна камера, ртсп поток которой мне нужно ретранслировать из этой изолированной локальной сети в сеть интернет)
все работает и без пляски с бубном до первого ребута серва( при последовательном перетыке сначала витухи с доступом в интернет, после уже подключения витухи с изолированной локаки. Проблема в том что время от времени каким то чудом линь начинает пытаться конектится к локалке, либо ребут и все падает( рдп клиент, ртсп поток). Ваши рекомендации по предварительной настройке уже выполнены.

Comment: Masquerading. Правка должна быть не менее 6 символов (с)

Comment: Читал статьи на данную тему, в каждой указывалось что нужно настроить конфиг interface. с добавлением статичных маршрутов и приоритетов подключения. Но в связи с тем что одна итерация ошибки занимает больше недели рисковать нельзя.


Есть ли какая либо возможность настроить один из сетевых интерфейсов как приоритетную. Чтобы сервер даже и не думал конектиться к изолированной локалке.

Comment: @user399811, так у вас вопрос не по настройке сети, а по поводу каких-то ошибок, которые вы описали тут в комментариях. вы лучше отдельные вопросы задайте по поводу отдельных ошибок.

Comment: @user399811, в новых вопросах не забудьте расшифровать, что именно вы подразумеваете под фразой «коннектиться к изолированной локалке». а то в такой формулировке совершенно непонятен её смысл.

Comment: @user399811, и, конечно, в этих новых вопросах от вас потребуется необходимая информация. начиная с содержимого `/etc/network/interfaces{,.d/*}` и вывода `$ ip a; ip r`

Comment: @user399811, просто догадка: возможно, за фразой «коннектиться к изолированной локалке» скрываются проблемы маршрутизации. ну, например, вы для обоих интрефейсов указали дефолтный шлюз. а надо было только для одного: того, который подключен к «внешнему миру».

Comment: Этим комментарием вы загнали меня в угол. Возможно в этом и крылась проблема( как только мне включат эту машину, я обязательно это проверю и отпишу). Заранее благодарю за проявленный интерес к моей проблеме.

Comment: маскарадинг не обязателен... можно обойтись правильно прописанными маршрутами на компьютерах в обеих подсетях...