# Как маршрутизировать трафик по впн

Tags: centos, маршрутизация, vpn

Интерфейс `ens33` использую как `прокси` (squid). Хочу маршрутизировать трафик с ens33 на ppp0. Как это сделать?

```
default via 192.168.2.1 dev ens33 proto static metric 100
10.84.0.1 dev ppp0 proto kernel scope link src 10.84.33.32
77.83.116.10 via 192.168.2.1 dev ens33 src 192.168.2.129
192.168.2.0/24 dev ens33 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.2.129 metric 100
```

Пробовал так route `add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev ppp0`
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ответ я написал исходя из предположения что трафик после прокси сервера хотите направить в интернет который по моему предложению находиться за ppp интерфейсом. Так много предположений из-за того, что в вопросе так мало информации :)

Comment: @СабирИсламов а что именно еще уточнить?

Comment: 1. https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1158332/178576 2. текстовую информацию лучше прилагать в виде текста: а) читать легче; б) можно копировать; в) поиск работает. исправить текст вопроса можно, нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса

Answer (score 0):

Нужно добавить маршрут
192.168.2.0./24 -> 10.84.0.1

Comment: я делал так - route add -net 192.168.2.0 netmask 255.255.255.0 dev ppp0

Comment: попробуй route add -net 192.168.2.0/24 gw 10.84.0.1